# Python pyatom: setting window size and position

Tags: python, pyatom

I've got a window that always loads up in my app at position x=780.0, y=222.0

I've been trying lots of different ways to change the window size and position however when I use `component.setString("AXPosition", {0,0})` I keep getting the following error: `atomacos.errors.AXErrorFailure: There is some sort of system memory failure.`

I must be doing something wrong but any advice would be appreciated.

If I use `component.AXPosition = {0,0}` I get no errors but the position has still not changed, however if I use `component.AXPosition = 0` or any number at all it always sets the position to x=0.0 y=1327.0 (the bottom left corner of my screen). ???

I've even tried a similar method to _converter.py in the repo but it still raises AXErrorFailure:

```
CGPoint=namedtuple("CGPoint", ("x", "y"))
from ApplicationServices import NSPointFromString
point = NSPointFromString("{x: 0, y: 0}")
component.AXPosition = CGPoint(point.x, point.y)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of digging, for those with a similar issue setting window sizes / positions this is the code:

```
    from ApplicationServices import AXValueCreate, kAXValueCGPointType
    import Quartz.CoreGraphics as CG

    x, y = 200, 300
    point = CG.CGPoint(x=x, y=y)
    component.AXPosition = AXValueCreate(kAXValueCGPointType, point)
```