# Programmatically change order of full screen apps on macOS with AppKit

Tags: macos, cocoa, fullscreen, nswindow, appkit

I’m trying to build a macOS utility that will allow me to programmatically change the order of full screen apps on my machine.

For example, let’s say the full screen apps on my machine are currently ordered as follows from left to right:

0. Chrome
1. iTerm
2. Xcode

I want to be able to call a method in AppKit to say something like “Move Xcode from full screen index 2 to index 0”. However, I can't identify an AppKit API that will help me do this.

- `NSScreen` only gives the physical displays, not the full screen apps / spaces
- `NSApplication` only gives the list of *my* app's windows
- `CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo` looked promising, but it doesn't have information about the order of full screen apps. It also doesn't allow me to get a `NSWindow` object to have any hope of *changing* the order

Is what I'm trying to do even possible with AppKit?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Spaces (desktops and fullscreen apps are both just spaces) are a feature of the system Window Manager and only manageable by the user through the app `Mission Control`.

Of course, the Window Manager needs to expose an API for management, otherwise how would `Mission Control` interact with it? But that API is not public.

Reverse engineered headers for those private APIs can be found online, e.g.
https://github.com/NUIKit/CGSInternal

With those headers in place, you can write code like this:

```
#import "CGSInternal/CGSSpace.h"

CGSSpaceID activeSpace = 
    CGSGetActiveSpace(_CGSDefaultConnection());
NSLog(@"activeSpace: %zu", activeSpace);

CFArrayRef spaceArray = 
    CGSCopySpaces(_CGSDefaultConnection(), kCGSAllSpacesMask);
NSLog(@"allSpaces: %@", (__bridge id)spaceArray);
```

But the usual warnings apply here:

You cannot commit code using private APIs to Apple's App Store. There is no official documentation, all that is known about that API has been reversed engineered and may not always be correct. As the API is not public, Apple can change it at any time without any previous warning and thus your working code could break with every system update.